# Changing R object names and pathway in a loop over a function

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, lapply

```
library('dplyr')
num_ens <- 10
```

I have a piece of code that takes `num_ens` files of data from a directory, reads them in, takes the average across them, and saves them as 1 object

```
A_tree <- lapply(1:num_ens, function(i) {
  # importing data on each index i
  r <- read.csv(
    paste0("/Users/sethparker/vox_LA_max/top_down_individ_sd1/ens_",i,"_0_tree_from_data.txt"), 
    header = FALSE
  )
  # creating add columns
  colnames(r) <- c("GPP","NPP","LA")
  r$month <- seq.int(nrow(r))
  r$run <- i
  
  return(r)
})
A_tree <- bind_rows(A_tree)
A_tree <- A_tree %>% group_by(month) %>% summarize(across(c(GPP,NPP,LA), mean))
```

I would like to auto automate this same process to go across 7 directories:

`/top_down_individ_sd1/` through `/top_down_individ_sd7/`

and to generate a series of objects:

`A_tree` through `G_tree`

I have unsuccessfully tried to achieve this with a few variations of the following for loop, which have yielded errors

```
letters <- LETTERS[seq(from = 1, to = 7)]
sd <- c("sd1","sd2","sd3","sd4","sd5","sd6","sd7")
```

```
for (j in 1:7) {
  paste0(letters[j],"_tree") <- lapply(1:num_ens, function(i) {
    # importing data on each index i
    r <- read.csv(paste0(paste0("/Users/sethparker/vox_LA_max/top_down_individ_",sd[j]),"/ens_",i,"_0_tree_from_data.txt"), 
                  header = FALSE)
    # creating add columns
    colnames(r) <- c("GPP","NPP","LA")
    r$month <- seq.int(nrow(r))
    r$run <- i
    
    return(r)
  })      
paste0(letters[j],"_tree") <- bind_rows(paste0(letters[j],"_tree"))
paste0(letters[j],"_tree") <- paste0(letters[j],"_tree") %>% group_by(month) %>% summarize(across(c(GPP,NPP,LA), mean))
}
```

How can I achieve this goal without errors

Comment: `paste0(letters[j],"_tree") <-` will not work use `assign(paste0(letters[j],"_tree"), value)` or the best define a empty `ll <- list()` and append it with `ll[[j]] <-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tree <- list()
for (j in 1:7) {
  tree[[j]] <- lapply(1:num_ens, function(i) {
    # importing data on each index i
    r <- read.csv(paste0(paste0("/Users/sethparker/vox_LA_max/top_down_individ_",sd[j]),"/ens_",i,"_0_tree_from_data.txt"), 
                  header = FALSE)
    # creating add columns
    colnames(r) <- c("GPP","NPP","LA")
    r$month <- seq.int(nrow(r))
    r$run <- i
    
    return(r)
  })      
  tree[[j]] <- bind_rows(tree[[j]])
  tree[[j]] <- tree[[j]] %>% group_by(month) %>% summarize(across(c(GPP,NPP,LA), mean))
}
```